# Dynamic (but uniform) column width in tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-matrix

How do I get tikz matrix of nodes to determine column width dynamically based on the the actual width of the text in each one (without me hard-coding each column width by hand)? Ideally, the table would be recognised by tikz as an object, so I can position other tikz objects in relation to it (right= of mat1, etc.). Here's a (very clunky) photoshop mockup of what I would like the output to look like:
[image]
My current setup changes node width for each individual node separately, I would like it to extend that to the whole column:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
matrix of nodes,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={rectangle,draw=black,align=center},
text depth=0.25ex,
text height=1ex,
nodes in empty cells
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table] (mat1)
{
Text&Long text&\\
&&Very long text\\
};\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You can quite easily achieve such an output using a regular `tabular` as in `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Text&Long text&\\
\hline
&&Very long text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}`. Is there a special reason for wanting to use a `tikz` `matrix` instead?

Comment: @Zarko thank you! I'd say about 70% of my LaTeX code comes from here anyway :D

Comment: @leandriis indeed, there's quite a bit of other things around the table I want to have (arrows, other tables, knot diagrams, etc.), so I gravitated towards tikz matrices.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simply by use of the `NiceTabular` defined in the `nicematrix` package (version 5.0 or newest) which is based on `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|}%
    \hline
Text    & Long text &               \\  \hline
        &           & Very long text\\  \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

After at least two compilation of the above MWE generate the following result:

[image]

**Addendum:**

As follows from your comment, your question is not clear. In the first try I consider, that you for some reason like to write table as TikZ `matrix`. Now is seems that you actually need table in some node, for example as shows the next image, which is part of some TikZ picture:

[image]

This can be simple accomplish by use standard of a table in TikZ node:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
\usepackage{hhline}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n1) [inner sep=0pt] {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}%
                                \hhline{|---|}
                            Text    & Long text &               \\
                                \hhline{|---|}
                                    &           & Very long text\\
                                \hhline{|---|}
                            \end{tabular}
                           };
\node (n2) [draw, rounded corners, align=left,
            right=of n1] {second\\ node};
\draw[very thick, -Straight Barb] (n1) -- (n2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, I can now see how by trying to keep the question short and precise I've excluded some key information. I would like the table to be recognised as an object by tikz, so I can position other tikz objects in relation to it (right= of mat1, etc.). Sorry about the convoluted setup.

Comment: @MihailHurmuzov, you can insert above table in some `tikz` node, or even better, a insert standard tabular in node ... See addendum to answer (will appear asap).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way could be using `\phantom{}` which is not part of any tikz library but a `\LaTeX` command to my knowledge.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
matrix of nodes,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={rectangle,draw=black,align=center},
text depth=0.25ex,
text height=1ex,
nodes in empty cells
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table]
{
Text&Long text&\phantom{Very long text}\\
\phantom{Text}&\phantom{Long text}&Very long text\\
};\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This becomes quite laborious (and possible more laborious than hardcoding column widths) if I have other text in the empty nodes (say "Text" above "Very long text").